# Searching a text with grep in Vim

Tags: grep, vim, search

i am doing some exercies in vim and i have a problem. I need to find a piece of text in another file in the same directory with my vim file. I used grep to find it but i had an error."bad situation"
 What i need to use to force grep to go out of vim file and search in "index.html" file ? Here is my grep code:

`i = ${grep data-buying index.html | grep USD | grep -oh '[0-9].[0-9]*' | head -n 1}`

What is wrong here ?

Comment: _"... but i had an error."_ - Any particular error? Or one of those other errors that definitely wouldn't help people answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try `:read !grep data-buying index.html | grep USD | grep -oh '[0-9].[0-9]*' | head -n 1`.

`:read !command` will run `command` and standard output will be read into the current buffer at the cursor's location.

Comment: It didn't work. :( Colon at the beginning is refers to bash command ?(im newbie here sorry :D ) If it is, i wrote that code sample in the vim, file name is blabla.sh. But i tried also in vim it didnt work.

Comment: The colon indicated you are sending vim into command mode by typing a colon, which provides a colon prompt.  You will then type `read !command` to execute `command` and import standard output into your current buffer as described.

Comment: I tried it either. It didnt work. it gives read : '!grep' :not a valid identifier.

Comment: Unable to replicate.

Comment: Try to run the same command but with full path of binaries like ":read !/usr/bin/grep data-buying index.html | /usr/bin/grep USD | /usr/bin/grep -oh '[0-9].[0-9]*' | /usr/bin/head -n 1"